# Unable to display categories at frontend in xcart

Tags: php, smarty, x-cart

I am using custom skin in xcart but I am unable to display categories and subcategories at frontend. But If I switch to default theme then It displays all the categories at frontend.

Where Iam doing wrong? I had googled it and also chat on helpdesk but no solution.

Answer (score 0):

The tips related to categories menu

1)disable the Flyout_Menus module

2)or disable ajax menu and delete var/cache dir

```
modules/Flyout_Menus/config.php
-define('XC_FLYOUT_MENU_TYPE', 'ajax');//Recommended value is 'ajax'
+define('XC_FLYOUT_MENU_TYPE', 'html');//Recommended value is 'ajax'
```

3)or remove skin/YOUR_SKIN_DIR/customer/categories.tpl file

Comment: with Flyout_Menus module enable categories and subcategories were coming but if I click on any category on subcatgory it gives a blank page. And after disabling Flyout_Menus module all coming categories and subcategories were disappered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910268/category-page-open-up-blank-in-xcart/38918323#38918323

Answer (score 0):

If your use **X-cart 5** then categories are displayed by `"XLite\View\TopCategories"` class.

It is added to `"sidebar.single"` and `"sidebar.first"` lists.

If you skin does not display sidebars, then you should add this class to another list.
For example, you can try to move class to another list by using the `"moveClassesInLists"` method:

```
namespace XLite\Module\Dev\MyModule;

abstract class Main extends \XLite\Module\AModuleSkin
{
    ...

    protected static function moveClassesInLists()
    {
        return array(
            'XLite\View\TopCategories' => array(
                array('sidebar.single', 'customer'),
                array('my_list', 10, 'customer'),
            ),
        );
    }
```