# category page open up blank in xcart

Tags: php, smarty, x-cart

I had updated my xcart site from 4.X.X version to 4.7.6 version. All works fine but the look and feel of my site changed completely. I was using 2-column skin in older version and I want exactly same look as that in old version, but after upgradation look of my site changes completely.

**What I had tried :**
To recover that I copy the same 2-column skin of older version in my new version, and it goes well. But now the problem is Iam not able to display categories.

**What I had tried :**
To recover the category issue I copied the categories.tpl file code of "common_files" skin in my custom skin in category.tpl file under customer folder.

**Still facing this problem**
Now categories are showing but if I click on any category it open up with a blank page

Answer (score 0):

1)Check the log files in your X-Cart installation in the var/log folder

2)Compare these tpls with your ones

> skin/common_files/customer/main/subcategories_t.tpl
>   skin/common_files/customer/main/subcategories_list.tpl
>   skin/common_files/customer/main/subcategories.tpl

3)Try to enable/disable this option
'Display subcategories list in multiple columns' on the page
http://YOUR_SHOP/admin/configuration.php?option=Appearance#tr_subcategories_per_row